# Eficientar consulta SQL

Tags: sql

Tengo una tabla que se llama numeros, en esta estan series de numeros telefonicos por ejemplo

```
5255, 'Mexico CDMX'
5233, 'Mexico Guadalajara'
5281, 'Mexico Monterrey'
```

Tengo un sp que recibe un numero completo ejemplo 525578547854, el sp debe decirme que ese numero pertenece a Mexico CDMX, actualmente como lo hago es lo siguiente

```
SELECT Destino FROM Numeros WHERE '525578547854' LIKE CONCAT(Codigo, '%')
```

Alguna idea de como hacerlo mas rapido?

El query toma 72 ms en ejecutarse

Gracias

Comment: Deberías solo enviar los cuatro primeros carácteres de tu teléfono. Por ejemplo, de `525578547854` solo `5255` e igualarlo con la columna `Codigo`, la cual debería tener un índice. Asimismo, deberías considerar el tipo numérico para la columna `Codigo`. Podrías indicarnos que versión y base de datos que estás usando.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero no es posible enviar solo los primeros 4 digitos, el sp recibe el numero completo, en base a eso es el problema, el SQL es SQL Server 2016

Comment: Solo es un comentario, podrías editar tu pregunta he indicarnos como realmente es tu procedimiento almacenado y como lo evaluas con la tabla.

Comment: Gracias, asi es la consulta: SELECT Destino FROM Numeros WHERE '525578547854' LIKE CONCAT(Codigo, '%')

Comment: ¿No me dices que es un procedimiento almacenado?

Comment: Si es un sp que hace otras consultas y calculos que no son relevantes para esta pregunta, en donde me atoro es en el SELECT que esta en la pregunta

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66158/discussion-between-davlio-and-salo-b).

Comment: simplemente ocupa `LEFT`?, `WHERE Codigo = LEFT(NumeroCompleto,4)`

Comment: El problema es que no siempre son 4 digitos, pueden ser mas o menos, con los que se haga el match

Comment: Puese en ese caso puedes usar `WHERE Codigo = LEFT(NumeroCompleto,LEN(Codigo))`

Comment: @Lamak Gracias por la idea, funciona bien